# ShareLatex Relative/Absolute Path Problem

Tags: input, sharelatex

In ShareLaTeX, I have the following folder/file structure:

```
- DIR1
 * FILE1
 * DIR2
      * FILE2

- DIR3
 * FILE3 (Preamble.tex)
 * DIR4 (Fonts)
     * DIR5
         * FILE5
```

(DIR1 and DIR3 are in the main DIR)

I need FILE1 and FILE 2 to access FILE3 inside DIR3. FILE3 accesses folders and files in DIR4.
In FILE1, I can do `\input{../DIR3/FILE3}` which will work only if FILE3 has `\setmainfont[Path=../DIR3/DIR4/DIR5]{FILE5}`

However, if in FILE2 I do `\input{../../DIR3/FILE3}` I get an error that says FILE5 cannot be found. 
If I change `\setmainfont[Path=../../DIR3/DIR4/DIR5]{FILE5}` in FILE3, FILE2 complies fine but now FILE1 does not compile.

I looked at the documentation for relative and absolute file paths but this seems to be a different issue. It seems to be FILE3 assumes the working directory of whatever file calls it, instead of its current directory.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

ShareLaTeX takes all paths to be from the 'root' directory of the project. It should work if:

- In FILE1 you write `\input{DIR3/FILE3}`
- In FILE2 you write `\input{DIR3/FILE3}`
- In FILE3 you write `\setmainfont[Path=DIR3/DIR4/DIR5]{FILE5}`